# VBA Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row Returning Incorrect Row

Tags: excel, vba

TIA for the help.

I am having a problem with the row for shapes returning an incorrect value. Here is my setup:
[image]

Each of the buttons on the right is named after the corresponding column header, the value in column A of the same row, and a number combining the row and column number (ex. Edit_555_10 would be the name of the first shape in cell G3). This ensures there are no duplicate names for when `Application.Caller` is used in the code.

All of the "Import Data" buttons run the same macro to import data. The Batch IDs have a corresponding sheet which the data is pasted to by using this code:

```
variable = Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
Worksheets(Range("A" & variable).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

However, during runtime, any and all "Import Data" buttons will return 3 when assigning a value to the variable. I have tested it with 3 different "Import Data" buttons in I3, I4, and I5 at the same time, each returning 3. During runtime I have moved the buttons to all areas of the sheet, and they all return row 3 every time. I have even moved all shapes out of row 3 and 4 so it wouldn't be possible to return 3, and it still returns 3.

All the "Edit" and "Create Tabs" buttons behave normally and have no problems. But for some reason, even without duplicate names, and setting the "Import Data" buttons down as far as row 8, they always return row 3 during runtime, which is obviously causing data to be put in the incorrect place.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code you use to receive the button name. I suppose that all your button have a single macro assigned... Try `Debug.Print Application.Caller`. Does it return the same for any clicked button? If yes, is it the name you are expecting?

Comment: Is it possible that the code you assigned to refer the other worksheet? This looks to be a reasonable supposition. Without seeing it, it is not possible to make such an observation and help you, from this point of view... Anyhow, **it is impossible that Application.Caller to wrongly return**. It may return an error, but not a wrong cell address.

Comment: Yes, ```Print Application.Caller``` returns the correct shape name each time. But will return 3 for the row no matter where that shape is moved to.

Comment: Try adding sheet reference infront of it (i.e. `WorkSheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row`)

Comment: There is a sheet reference in front, i just didn't include it here. But I have checked that and it is looking into the correct sheet for the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually figured it out. But I am still confused as to why it is happening.

When pressing the "Edit" button, an option is to delete the entry. This grabs the row from `Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row` and sets it to a variable. It then deletes the entry with `Range("A" & variable & ":I" & variable).Delete xlShiftUp` When doing this, the "Edit" and "Create Tabs" buttons are deleted no problem. However, the "Import Data" buttons are just scrunched up to 0 height and end up between I2 and I3. So every time I had deleted the entries in the past, it just kept adding to the stack of invisible buttons; meaning when I was running a test with the same names, there were 10 or so duplicate buttons for each unique name, and the row of one of the invisible buttons was returned.

My workaround for this is to cycle through the shapes, compare each `Shapes(name).TopLeftCell.Row` with `Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row` and delete the shapes in the same row.

So while the problem is fixed, I am not sure why the "Edit" and "Create Tabs" buttons were deleted correctly each time while the "Import Data" buttons remained and were scrunched to be invisible. If anyone has thoughts I would be interested.

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted the full code for the miscreant Shapes, but if you substitute your code for the *Import Data* Shapes with:

```
Dim s As Shape, r As Long, sname As String

sname = Application.Caller
Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(sname)
r = s.TopLeftCell.Row
MsgBox r
```

do you get a different value for each Shape ??

Comment: I get the correct ```Application.Caller``` but r is 3 every time.